# Importing from textfile with macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue where i want to import value from a textfile into my excel-document which it does but when i run macro over and over to refresh said values with new ones it just moves it over and adds more, it needs to delete values and replace them, i didnt write this code myself so i cant understand the issue with it so here i am pleading for help

```
Sub ImportSaldo()
Call Shell("C:\import\GetFromFTP.bat", vbNormalFocus)

Dim fileName As String, folder As String

folder = "c:\import\"
fileName = "Saldot.txt"

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1").Select

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & fileName, Destination:=ActiveCell)
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
.TextFilePlatform = 850
.TextFileStartRow = 1
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1").Select` is your problem here. If you want the existing code to be forced to load the data to A1, remove that line and change `Destination:=ActiveCell` on your `.Add` line to `Destination:=Range("A1")`.

Comment: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for saldot.txt (188178 Bytes).
> Replace Existing File with Temp File:I/O Error
226 Transfer complete. 188┬á178 bytes transferred. 183,77 KB/sec.
ftp: 188178 bytes received in 0,31Seconds 603,13Kbytes/sec.
ftp>

I/O Error and crashed Excel when i did your change.

Answer (score 0):

.RefreshOnFileOpen = False change this to True

Once the file is opened it should clear the existing values in the ActiveSheet.

Comment: This didnt work either, it just moves previous data to the right

Comment: Update LIne 4: ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate     Comment out existing with an ' 'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1").Select  ~  you can always remove it to make the code active again.  Happy to look at the file if you continue to have issues.

Comment: Still doing the same thing, thanks for the help but ill just manually update my warehouse stock-value file until later notice